# Getting file size 0 when changing input file value on tests in CentOS

Tags: angularjs, automated-tests, protractor

I'm facing an issue trying to upload a file from my tests, I'm using Protractor to test and am able to sendKeys to the file and get the filename, lastModified attributes, but the file size comes as 0, and the actual size is 53:

[See the full logs here](https://snap-ci.com/rafbgarcia/test/branch/master/logs/defaultPipeline/1/FileUploadTest?back_to=build_history) and [here is the code](https://github.com/rafbgarcia/test)

```
property=lastModifiedDate
  value=Fri Jul 18 2014 15:57:29 GMT+0000 (UTC)
property=name
  value=e2eUpload-1.txt
property=type
  value=text/plain
property=size
  value=0

==============================================

$ ls -la ./test/sample
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 2 go go 4096 Jul 18 15:57 .
drwxrwxr-x 3 go go 4096 Jul 18 15:57 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 go go   53 Jul 18 15:57 e2eupload-1.txt
```

There is also an artifact which you can download here which shows the file info in the browser: https://snap-ci.com/rafbgarcia/test/branch/master

Just click on the save to drive icon above the user's commit.

The tests run in a CentOS environment using Chrome v35.

Tests fails on Ubuntu too, but they run fine on MacOS.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and it turned out I was entering the path to the file incorrectly.  It may help to add a check in your protractor test before .sendKeys(path) to make sure the file you are entering actually exists.

```
if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
    throw new Error('file "' + path + '" does not exist');
}
```